# Vectorized exponentiation

Tags: matlab, octave, exponentiation

I have two vectors, `X` of bases and `N` of exponents. I want to get the matrix of all values `e = xn` for each `x` in `X` and `n` in `N`.

For example, the following input:

```
X = [2 3 4]'
N = [1 2 3]
```

should produce:

```
ans = [2 4 8; 3 9 27; 4 16 64]
```

Is there a way to get this without looping (just like you can get all values of x×n by using the column by row product)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@power, X, N)
```

This assumes that `X` is a column vector and `N` is a row vector. If you want to guarantee that, use the following syntax which is more robust:

```
bsxfun(@power, X(:), N(:).')
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. (And shame on me, I stumbled upon a similar problem solved with bsxfun just a week ago.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit sloppier than the `bsxfun` answer, but you could use `meshgrid`:

```
E = X.^(meshgrid(N)')
```

This assumes both `X` and `N` are row vectors. If both are column vectors then it becomes:

```
E = X.^(meshgrid(N))
```